# System.Web.Caching with WebSockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, websocket

Is it possible to use classes from the `System.Web.Caching` namespace with an ASP.NET application which uses WebSockets?

Comment: Can you restate your question please?  In particular, why are you worried that data caches are incompatible with WebSockets?

Comment: Im not worried, cache works in webservice, or any pageload event.  Instead of voting  down answer the question

Comment: I don't understand your question.  That's why I suggested you update it.

Comment: I juat edited, feel free to correct it

Comment: If we don't understand it, we can't "correct" it.

Comment: OK, I just change the quetion.

Comment: I rewrote it for you, and cancelled out the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using ASP.NET 4.5, since [ASP.NET WebSockets are only available natively starting with that version](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097383).

Regardless, I don't see any reason why [`System.Web.Caching.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) wouldn't work in an ASP.NET application that happens to use [ASP.NET WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Do you see some specific issue which makes you think the two features are not compatible? If so, please change your question to give details about the specific issue, and someone will probably be able to help you.

Follow-up:

MSDN says:

> The Cache class is not intended for use outside of ASP.NET applications. It was designed and tested for use in ASP.NET to provide caching for Web applications. For other types of applications, such as console applications or Windows Forms applications, use the ObjectCache class.

SuperSocket describes itself as:

> ... a light weight, cross platform and extensible socket application framework.... SuperSocket can run as console application and windows service.

That suggests to me it has nothing to do with ASP.NET. Therefore, no, follow the documentation and don't use [`System.Web.Caching.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx). Try [`System.Runtime.CachingObjectCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have decided to use open source WebSocket (SuperSocket) with use of ASP.net 4.0.  Is System.Web.Caching.Cache use for page load event (for example for WebServices)? As in WebSocket you do not need to load the page to retrieve the data! For that reason I do not think  the System.Web.Caching.Cache will work.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful information but I still think cache (System.Runtime.CachingObjectCache) won't work in Websocket.  I think, to retrive  the data from cache you need to load th page or do server polling!!

Comment: `System.Web.Caching.Cache` is the one that's tied to ASP.NET, and is different from `System.Runtime.CachingObjectCache` - which will *definitely* work.